# How do i add textbox values to Access database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, ms-access

I  want to add textbox values to relevant columns in access database, the connection has been established but when i click the submit button the values are not added.
here is the code i tried, any help is appreciated

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string EmailAddress = TextBox1.Text;
    string UserName = TextBox2.Text;
    string Password = TextBox3.Text;

    try
    {
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = C:\Users\Bheki Ndhlovu\source\WebSites\WebSite8\App_Data\UserDatabase.accdb; Persist Security Info = False;");

        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO User(EmailAddress, UserName, Password) VALUES(@EmailAddress, @UserName, @Password)");
        con.Open();


         if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
         {
             TextBox1.Text = "sssss";

             cmd.Parameters.Add("@EmailAddress", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text;
             cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox2.Text;
             cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox3.Text;

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();

         }


    }
    catch (Exception error)
    {
        //Show error message as    error.Message
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps in the Page_Load method you do not have a if(!isPostback) and  so the value of the `TextBoxes` are getting reset on a `postback` before the `Button1_Click` method is executed.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `connection string` with `OleDbCommand`.

```
cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO User(EmailAddress, UserName, Password) VALUES(@EmailAddress, @UserName, @Password)",con);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example were all data operations reside in a class. If the add new record is successful the new primary key is returned. On failure you can query the exception that raised the problem for failure.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.IO;

namespace MS_AccessAddNewRecord_cs
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void addRecordButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var ops = new Operations();
            var newId = 0;
            if (ops.AddNewRow(companyTextBox.Text, contactNameTextBox.Text, contactTitleTextBox.Text, ref newId))
            {
                newIdentifierTextBox.Text = $"{newId}";
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"{ops.Exception.Message}");
            }
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// This class should be in a separate class file, I placed it here for easy of learning
    /// </summary>
    public class Operations
    {
        private OleDbConnectionStringBuilder Builder = new OleDbConnectionStringBuilder
        {
            Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0",
            DataSource = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Database1.accdb")
        };

        private Exception mExceptiom;
        public Exception Exception
        {
            get
            {
                return mExceptiom;
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Add a new record, upon success return the new primary key for the record in pIdentifier parameter
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="pName"></param>
        /// <param name="pContactName"></param>
        /// <param name="pContactTitle"></param>
        /// <param name="pIdentfier"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public bool AddNewRow(string pName, string pContactName, string pContactTitle, ref int pIdentfier)
        {
            bool Success = true;

            try
            {
                using (OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection { ConnectionString = Builder.ConnectionString })
                {
                    using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand { Connection = cn })
                    {
                        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Customers (CompanyName,ContactName, ContactTitle) " + 
                                                          "Values(@CompanyName,@ContactName, @ContactTitle)";

                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompanyName", pName);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactName", pContactName);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactTitle", pContactTitle);

                        cn.Open();

                        int Affected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        if (Affected == 1)
                        {
                            cmd.CommandText = "Select @@Identity";
                            pIdentfier = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Success = false;
                mExceptiom = ex;
            }

            return Success;

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If EmptyWaterHole's answer is not the problem, is it erroring out on the connection?

Be sure 'VarChar' is the correct data type for each of the fields.

Also, be sure the values do not exceed the size (ie: if you set the field to only allow up to 25 characters and your value is over 25 characters, the value will not be added).

In addition, if you are not allowing nulls and one of the values exceeds the limit, the whole record will not be added.

Answer (score 0):

Mr. Hungry.  Try it like this.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            OleDbConnection conn;
            conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0;Data Source=C:\your_path_here\Northwind.mdb");

            conn.Open();

            OleDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();

            cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO MyExcelTable([Fname], [Lname],  [Address])VALUES('" + textBox1.Text + "', '" + textBox2.Text + "','" + textBox3.Text + "')";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();

        }

        public OleDbConnection myCon { get; set; }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Ryan\Desktop\Coding\Microsoft Access\Northwind.mdb";

            string fstName  = textBox1.Text.Trim();
            string lstName  = textBox2.Text.Trim();
            string adres = textBox3.Text.Trim();
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(@"INSERT INTO MyExcelTable (FName, LName, Address) VALUES (@FName, @LName, @Address)")
            {
                Connection = conn
            };

            conn.Open();

            if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                // you should always use parameterized queries to avoid SQL Injection
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@FName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = fstName;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@LName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = lstName;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Address", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = adres;

                try
                {
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    MessageBox.Show(@"Data Added");
                    conn.Close();
                }
                catch (OleDbException ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Source + "\n" + ex.Message);
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show(@"Connection Failed");
            }
        }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this it will work if you are using access as your database

```cs
try
{
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
    command.Connection = connection;
    command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO REPORT (patientName,tel,hostel,id no,department,diagnose,gender) values(@patientName,@tel,@hostel,@id no,@department,@diagnose,@gender)";
    connection.Open();
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@patientName", textBox1.Text);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tel", textBox2.Text);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hostel", textBox3.Text);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id no", textBox4.Text);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@department", textBox5.Text);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@diagnose", richTextBox1.Text);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", textBox6.Text);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    connection.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("Patient record Have been save successfully....");

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("error" + ex);
}
```